# Auto-summarising JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to summarise JSON data objects in a webpage.  The only method I can think of is to read it into R, run `summarise()`, extract the report to json and read that into a webpage and write to DOM.  Does anyone know a less idiotic method for getting an equivalent intelligent summary that doesn't involve R?

Comment: This question is off topic because you're asking for a tool or framework. If you tried to implement something to do this yourself and had code trouble which you could show us then it would be on topic.

Comment: Unduly inflexible attitude IMO.  How can I have a specific coding question about a method I don't exists?  It's still a query about a specific javascript method with a specific input and output.

Comment: Grateful if you could point to meta guidance on this point if you're going to vote to close.

Comment: The close reason they're using is already quite clear: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."* I've tried to offer a non-library answer.

Comment: That advice is IMO misguided.  So if you mention 'any library?' you break the rules!  I've asked plenty of questions in SO along the lines "does a library do this?" and always had positive responses.  Ever heard of spirit vs letter?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything equivalent in Javascript/JQuery for JSON objects?

The closest thing is probably `Object.keys` and `Array#reduce`, which visits each array entry (each property name — key — in this case) and calls the callback passing the accumulator for the reduce operation and the value of the entry. So for instance, a sum looks like this:

```js
var obj = {
  foo: 42,
  bar: 27,
  baz: 51
};
var sum = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(acc, key) {
  return acc + obj[key];
}, 0); // <== 0 = seed value for the accumulator
snippet.log(sum);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Other than that, you're into libraries.